# Managing different versions of Browser (Chrome for example) while using Selenium 4.9.1 in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

We are using Selenium with **C#** for our GUI Tests. Currently we are using WebdriverManager to handle diffrerent versions of Chrome auotmatically. It works fine so far !

I recently tried to update Selenium Webdriver version to latest (4.9.1). I am aware that in Java when one has Selenium Webdriver version 4.0.0 onards, one does not need WebdriverManager anymore. It will be taken care by Selenium Webdriver. But in C# it does not seem so. I could not run tests wehn I removed WebdriverManager (Error - Session can not be cretaed). So my questions below :-

1. While using Selenium Webdriver with C#, what should one use for handling different versions of the Browser ? WebdriverManager or Selenium Manager ?
2. Is there any advantage of one over the other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) directly since it is the official driver manager for Selenium WebDriver.

Note: I am the maintainer of [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) (for Java). But also, I am developing Selenium Manager. I don't know the details of [WebDriverManager.Net](https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net), which is the one you are using.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the support you providing to the community ! You are right. Selenium Manager being official driver Manager for selenium makes more sense. I will try to replace WebdriverManager with that. (For info :- I am currently using WebDriverManager 2.16.2 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebDriverManager/)